# Extracting Numenator and Denominator of Rational Data Type in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I have declared rational data types in a list data like this:

```
from sympy import *
lst = list()
lst[0]=Rational(0,1)
lst[1]=Rational(3,14)
lst[2]=Rational(1,7)
lst[3]=Rational(9,14)
```

How do i extract the numerator and denominator part i.e. lst[0].denominator ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.p` and `.q` attributes:

```
In [7]: r = Rational(2, 3)

In [8]: r
Out[8]: 2/3

In [9]: r.p
Out[9]: 2

In [10]: r.q
Out[10]: 3
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.numbers.Rational

Comment: Thanks for the answer i was unable to find it in documentation because I was looking here: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html